# iphone send video to ipad live streaming and wireless control (like AR Drone)

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, wireless

How can I send video from an iPhone to an iPad?

I'm building a robot that is an iPhone controlling an arduino, for the next phase I would like to be able to send some live streaming video from the iPhone to see in an iPad and have the iPad sending commands to the iPhone.

so how to send live streaming video from one device to the other (WiFi preferred or BlueTooth), and how to control one device via  wireless from the other?

EDIT:
The best example for what I intend to do is the [Parrot AR Drone](http://ardrone.parrot.com/parrot-ar-drone/usa/how-does-it-work) and another app for the toy,
[app clone to pilot the Quadracopter](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/drone-master/id417853103?mt=8&ls=1)

The difference is that I would be getting the image from an iPhone and sending the control orders to the iPhone [from an iPad] as well, not a separate hardware.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Awesome question - I hope someone answers it

Comment: This guy is streaming video between two ipads: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6p5mbp_M98

Comment: @fredw He is streaming video using FaceTime as described in the video description. I cant see how your comment is usefully related to the OPs question.

Comment: maybe this helps

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142363/how-to-integrate-live555-in-xcode-ios-sdk

Answer (score 1):

Most of the apps I've seen that do this use AVFoundation to capture data form the video camera - then push the frames to a server somewhere.  You probably won't want to push every frame.  For the receiving side of things I would have a server hosting a web page with an html5 video tag looking at an m3u8 playlist.  Have your files from the iphone go into the playlist folder.

```
<video src="http://yourserver.com/path/to/stream/yourPlaylist.m3u8">
    Your browser does not support the VIDEO tag
</video>
```

Then set your view on the ipad or computer to look at that webpage.  There is for sure a more direct way of sending the files straight to the ipad for viewing - but I like being able to view the video from any broswer :)

If you want to stay away from a web view on the ipad you can also get the files as you would retrieve any file over a network.  The web view is just the easiest way in my opinion.

Comment: hi, thanks. I will look into this implementation to experiment with it, but I will prefer something not based on a web service, just from device to device, cheers

Comment: it should be a similar implementation - you'll set up the network connection then send the files to a directory on the ipad where the ipad will read from

Answer (score 1):

[How to integrate Live555 in XCode (iOS SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142363/how-to-integrate-live555-in-xcode-ios-sdk)

hope this helps!