# How to integrate Live555 in XCode (iOS SDK)

Tags: h.264, rtsp, live555

I have to implement the live streaming from iphone to wowza server using rtsp h264. I did search and found one library Live555. I created the .a files along with include headers. But I am not able to use them in my XCode. As I used then then it start giving errors in understanding the c++ keyword "class". This is maybe because of .hh files.

Is anyone having idea, how to include live555 in ios application.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Its fairly easy but I to long an explanation for here, maybe we can chat or something, or if you have a specific build question just post it here in detail.

Comment: Thanks Michelle to reply on this. I am new on stack. Could you suggest any medium so that we can chat or skype etc.

Comment: thanks Michelle to share this.

Comment: hey, do you have sample code or sample url or sample project for using live555 in xcode

Comment: @MichelleCannon Are you still willing to explain how to integrate Live555 with Xcode? Because I have libLive555.a compiled from github https://github.com/weevilgenius/live555-ios but now I'm stuck

Comment: yes, its not the easiest thing to do but once you do it once , Unfortunately I am out of town until next tuesday , when I get back I would be more than willing to share code with you. are you trying to build a player or a server solution, I've down both . live 555 works fairly well on iOS but you will need to do some minor customization.